# Adobe XD: Can't change link group only in one artboard

Tags: adobe-xd

I'm prototyping a desktop ribbon application. I've created the basic main screen artboard "Geral - ir para sede municipal":
[image]

Then duplicated it to artboard "Geral - abrir galeria de favoritos" as in the image bellow:
[image]

Whatever I change the "Galeria" group in one artboard, the change is beeing reflected in other artboards. I would like to change only the working artboart and let aother ones as they are. The image bellow shows my issue:
[image]

The portuguese stuff are just texts, hope it did not prejudice the undestanting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. Linked groups keep theirselves and their children object styles across artboards. So to solve my issue I just have to change the "Ferramentas"  parent object to be a common group instead of a linked group.